# Is there a way to make a copy of a project within the same workspace?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a basic photo album project in eclipse.  I would like to make specialize photo albulm projects base on it.

Is there a way I could copy my phtotalbulm project into a new project, same eclipse workspace,  and say call it something like carphotoabulm??????

Comment: yes. but you also can use your project as a library to avoid having several versions of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to implement your already existing code in another specialised application project , I think it is better to use your previous project as a **library** and reference it in your new project. That way, all the various classes in `PhotoAlbum` would be accessible to you in your `CarPhotoAlbum`. It can be considered analogous to Inheritance where the parent class can us used as a base class for the specialisations in the derived child class.

**To create a clone of your project :** Open the project that you want to copy. Copy and Paste using Cntrl-C and Cntrl-V . When you finish pasting,  Eclipse will ask you for a new project name. The Eclipse project name and directory are independent of the application name and package.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483539/android-copy-existing-project-with-a-new-name) for more details.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the idear.  I never made my own library in java before, sort of learning it as I learn how to program the Android.  I don't know if this would work becouse I would like to make chnages to the UI, such as chnaging the names and graphics in the xml files.

Comment: Well, since you want to change the graphics in the xml files, I guess you could go for cloning the project instead of making a library. Even I havnt worked with libraries enough to know if the xml layouts can be changed. Anyway, check out my updated answer. Should solve your problem. :)