# Copy 'project' in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, copy

I have copied a 'project' with these steps -
1. right click on project name, select 'copy'
2. right click in the file explorer view, 'paste'
3. here it gave me a dialog to select the target copy directory, so I selected a new one

Now everything is copied, but whenever I try to reach a source xml from activity, i.e. ctrl+click on `R.layout.file_name`, it opens file from my previous project (the one which I copied from).

What did I miss here?

Comment: Try import project. Check whether this happens after importing.

Comment: @Paritosh : Let me check

Comment: And people will downvote but never suggest where the question should be improved.

Comment: It did not work. I deleted whole project, copied through file explorer, imported it, and changed it's gradle application id. Followed this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324555/android-copy-existing-project-with-new-name-in-android-studio, thought I thought there has to be a way of copying and using it directly.