# Duplicate an Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, duplicates

I'm using Android studio and I'm trying to deplicate an existing project to make another new project.

I search in the web and the forum and I found this method:

- copy the folder of the old project and rename it
- change the package name in the `andoidmanifest.xml` directly from disc
- do the same with the build gradle file (the file with Java sources)
- open the new project with Android Studio
- make a refact--> rename to change the package name of my souces package
- I open the Java classes and I changed manually the pachage name
- then I tried to make a gradle sync

The problem is that the sync faild and I failed to make my new project.

How can I copy an Android Studio project to a new one?

Comment: This may help you [Stack overflows another answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324555/android-copy-existing-project-with-new-name-in-android-studio

Comment: tnks, i saw this answer but did it but always i got a sync failed msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had a virtual machine problem. The solution is:

1. open file -> settings
2. click to compiler
3. in the VM option field put the following value: `-Xmx512m`