# Creating different app with the same project (AndroidStudio)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have to test something on my app. I do want create another apk with the same project but i have to install both, the latest and the old one. How can i possible to do this without creating a new prject?  thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can do it  with a buildType. Something like:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }

}
```

Or you can do it with a flavor

```
 productFlavors {
        f1 {
            applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.f1"
        }
        f2 {
            applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.f2"
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my night.

Comment: @MarkGallos mark the answer if it soves your issue. It can help other users.

Answer (score -3):

see this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18329481/5649082

according to this link

1. copy your project to another directory and rename folder
2. open it in android studio
3. right click on package name and refactor -> rename
4. (optional) change app name in res-> values and in build.gradle -> defaultConfig -> applicationId