# Android Studio error when trying to copy and rebuild project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to copy and build a different project so that I can change a few things for a practice problem in the Android Dev tutorials. I've gone ahead and followed both the guide on how to copy a project here: https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/appendix/appendix-utilities/appendix-utilities.html

and a.t.'s answer here: [Copy existing project with a new name in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324555/copy-existing-project-with-a-new-name-in-android-studio)

but both have failed me after multiple tries.

Here is where I get an error,at step 11 on a.t.'s answer when I go to sync gradle files, after I've changed the name of the project elsewhere, it gives me these 2 errors:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.HelloToast3.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3.
```

This is my project `build.gradle` and my Module App `build.gradle` respectively

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.HelloToast3.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.HelloToast3.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.HelloToast3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-HelloToast3-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I'm new to android studio, maybe this is a simple fix but I can't find the solution yet. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i understand your problem but not completely. I want to give my advise to you, when you import any outer project to android studio, you should do it indirectly. To solve any kind of gradle or build error, you can do it, it is very simple.

1. Make a empty project using android studio and close it
2. Copy all class and res folder from your project what you want to import it to android studio to your new created empty project
3. Now import new project rather than your old project