# Project name in android

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi, I created  a project in eclipse . I have  a project name on a a different computer but it is a different project . Everytime  i try to `import` this new  project it reads the project.properties file and gives me an error saying `cannot import project as the name is already in use` .

Please help .

Comment: try to use Existing Android Project

Comment: Try in a new workspace. File->switch workspace->new .... and then you try to import

Comment: change the project name ?!

Comment: @User : This is how i am doing it . but when it imports , it finds the project file of the new project and  the pne  alreaady n my eclipse to be  same and  does not allow me to import the new  one ...

Comment: wats the problem change the any of the project name

Comment: This link may help you to resolve issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483539/android-copy-existing-project-with-a-new-name

Answer (score 1):

Try this. When importing,

Uncheck the **copy projects into workspace** checkbox.

Then click **refresh** button.

Comment: Is this answer a copy of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9053087/379693)?

Comment: @PareshMayani Actually not. I'm also faced with same problem. This is how to i solve it.

Comment: Do you have previously opened project with same name in Eclipse when importing new project ? You can't open two projects with same name at once. you have change name of one project. (ex: Project_01 and Project_02)

Answer (score 0):

You may have project with the same name or this issue is being raised due to the same of name of Main activity the particular you are trying to import.

**For example:** Most of the project has MainActivity.java and if you try to import it then it shows the same error.

Comment: Like i said i know that i already haave  a prooject with this name ... but now both are working projects on two different computers . I cant lose any .... thats why i asked a  way where i can import the new project ....

Comment: Yes while importing project name, change activity name to different name.

Answer (score 0):

okey ...please change the names of the projects, each project in eclipse is identified with names ..don't just rename the project folder, instead right click on the project in package explorer and rename from Refractor

Comment: both are working projects on two different computers . I cant lose any .... thats why i asked a way where i can import the new project .... i am scared , refactoring might make  one  of them not working

Answer (score 0):

first delete your project from your project explorer and then import it..

Comment: both are working projects on two different computers . I cant lose any .... thats why i asked a way where i can import the new project ....

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the .project and .classpath file from your existing folder from where you are importing the project.

Comment: You mean for the new one or the old one ?

Comment: The project let say if in "A" Folder. copy the project into B folder and remove stated files from B folder and then import the code from B folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `workspace folder`, create a new folder and paste your project in that folder. Go to eclipse and `import the project` from file Menu, make sure Uncheck `copy projects into workspace` before importing.

Comment: Both are alreaady in different workspaces.. the trouble is they aare being imported under the ssame  package  explorer ie for eclipse .