# Problems with Android and Eclipse when Run on Device

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I duplicate my project on eclipse and renamed it but, when I run the new project the first one is replaced by the old one and vice-versa.

The Projects have differents names.

Tks
Adriano Silvestre

Comment: You must have different package name

Answer (score 0):

Renamed? You mean you changed the package in the manifest?

Comment: Hum... Is this line that I need change:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="com.simonmacdonald.scan" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="5" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
??
tks

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed package names? (`package` property in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and package names in source code as well)

Comment: Hum... Is this line that I need change: <manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.simonmacdonald.scan" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="5" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"> ?? tks

Comment: That's correct. Just make sure that `package` attribute is different for both copies of the project. As far as I know, changing `package` name will force you to refactor the packages in source code as well.

Comment: Tks guy!! It´s Working now!

Comment: Glad it worked :) By the way, welcome to Stackoverflow. If any answer was useful, please, consider upvoting/mark right answer, as it may be useful for other users too :)

Answer (score 0):

For creating a copy of project you must use different **PackageName** only changing **project name** is not sufficient

Do the following

1. you just copy your project into new one (<kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> & <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>).
2. you change package-name in your manifest
3. After that you must rename your main package with refactor. Don't forget to select.
4. Just change your application name in manifest
5. application `android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="new name"`

Hope I didn't forget something and it helps you

[Android Copy Existing Project With A New Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483539/android-copy-existing-project-with-a-new-name)