# Duplicating an existing android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

i am trying to copy an existing android project to a different location and importing it so that i don't mess with the original project.
but the classes are still pointing to the old location and not the new location

any help will be appreciated.

i tried the solution in 
[Android - copy existing project with a new name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483539/android-copy-existing-project-with-a-new-name)
but it didnt work

Comment: Remove all intellyJ idea stuff from the copy. I mean the iml files and the .idea folder. Then import the copy over the gradle file. Android studio will create new iml files pointing to the correct place. Or you can open all iml and other config files (they are xml) and change pathes manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a fresh copy. Delete .idea folder and .iml files. Then try importing again.