# Package being replaced Android

Tags: android, eclipse, package

I imported the same project twice in Eclipse and, changed the name and renamed the package (Refactor).
Why does it not install as a seperate app then?

I checked the Manifest file and it was also updated to the new package name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483539/android-copy-existing-project-with-a-new-name

Comment: This is vague, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the Packagename in AndroidManifest has changed. That is the essential declaration.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="new.package.name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Refactor (Rightclick on the project and package) to rename the project and the package is the right approach, but I also had to rename the package name in the Manifest (it somehow didn't update it automatically)